# Double bar delimiter broken by gb4e package

Tags: delimiters, gb4e

I was trying to utilize the double bar delimiters `\|` and `\|`. The output should be of the form `||P||`, but with the `gb4e` package only a single vertical bar gets printed. How can I fix this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\newcommand{\dbar}[1]{\left\|#1\right\|}

\begin{document}

$\dbar{P}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use `\lVert` and `\rVert` from `amsmath` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\newcommand{\dbar}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}

\begin{document}

$\dbar*{P}$

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Another option is to use `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathtools`, in this case, however, you need the `\noautomath` command from `gb4e` to prevent problems that arise from `gb4e` modifications that allow to use `^` and `_` outside math-mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\noautomath
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\dbar{\lVert}{\rVert}

\begin{document}

$\dbar{P}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Stumbled upon a similar solution just a few seconds ago. Do you know why `\|` breaks in this situation? Something to do with how `gb4e` messes with the catcodes or something along those lines?

Comment: @Dennis Yes, that's my guess too. In fact, I was going to propose a solution with `mathtools` and `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`, but `gb4e` interferes again with `mathtools`.

Comment: If you use the `\noautomath` command below the package call for `gb4e` that removes the modifications to the catcodes of `^` and `_` and allows the use of `mathtools` (i.e., it gets rid of the `TeX capacity exceeded...` error). In fact, that's exactly the solution I stumbled upon just before you posted.

Comment: @Dennis Yes. I was just reading the `gb4e` documentation and had found this option. I updated my answer. Thanks!